# Syncing box.com

Tags: sync, cloud

I am attempting to access my box.com drive on a linux machine. I followed the steps at: [Box-linux-sync](https://github.com/noiselabs/box-linux-sync/tree/42dcda5e07df1b45eb451a6b1265d052f3254ff3) and I'm able to finish the steps without error until it prompts me to enter a username and password upon which I'm greeted with a server timeout like so [image]

I used my account email address as the username. (And obviously I checked that I have a working internet connection.) I am using the free version of box at the moment but I will eventually be using the enterprise version.

Any idea on why this might not be working? Has it been deprecated? It's been a while since the repository has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this client does not support enterprise Box accounts which was what I was using. Oh well...